# Does GitHub Actions API requests limit refer to API calls of GitHub APIs or to general HTTP calls?

Tags: github-actions

According to the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/usage-limits-billing-and-administration#usage-limits)

> API requests - You can execute up to 1000 API requests in an hour across all actions within a repository. If exceeded, additional API calls will fail, which might cause jobs to fail.

Does this apply to requests to the GitHub API or does it mean that we can just make 1,000 API calls to any provider per hour?

If yes, is there a way to lift the requirement because we may want to run integration tests on our platform from GitHub Actions and this limit may be surpassed very fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit refers to GitHub API requests.

GitHub Actions has no opinions about your API requests to non-GitHub services.

There is also *probably* some sort of external network connection limit on Actions, but it isn't that low and I can't seem to find it mentioned in their docs.